# How can I find the definition of methods/operations defined in an implicitly-converted class?

Tags: scala

I'm looking at someone else's source code (Scala), where I see the operator `:+=` being called on a variable of type [IndexedSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq).  I am looking all over the scaladocs page for that class to figure out what that operator does, but I do not see it.  I'm thinking that either it's defined in a class outside of `IndexedSeq`'s inheritance hierarchy, or else the javascript on the scaladocs page is hiding it somewhere I can't see it. (Actually it's neither; see answer below.)

I've hit every button on the scaladocs page trying to unhide everything. I've looked in the web-page's HTML code.  There has got to be a way to look up an operator from the documentation of a class to which it can be applied.  Hasn't there?

(*N.B.*: I looked up that operator using [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/), so I know what that operator means now.  This question is about scala documentation in general, not that particular operator.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All operators in Scala are normal methods.

You cannot find it because it is **compiler magic** for re-assignement, it is *not* an operator. Or to say it another way: it looks like an operator of its own, but it is actually "an operator followed by the `=` character".

The compiler will magically turn that into a assignment if the operator (here `:+`) returns the proper type, and the original value was a `var`, obviously.

Since it is not provided by any implicit nor explicit method on `Seq[T]` or whatever, it does not appear anywhere in the generated scaladoc.

So to answer the general question:

- It is a language construct, so the only place where it is documented is the specification, sadly,
- but, if you find some `"<?>="` unknown operator somewhere, look for the definition of `"<?>"`, that one is sure to be documented.

---

**Edit**: I finally found where this is defined in the SLS:

> §6.12.4:
>
> An assignment operator is an operator symbol (syntax category op in (§1.1)) that
>   ends in an equals character “=”, with the exception of operators for which one of the
>   following conditions holds:
>
> (1) the operator also starts with an equals character, or
>
> (2) the operator is one of (<=), (>=), (!=).

It also says later on that it only happens when all other options have been tried (including potential implicits).

Comment: That's a good one.  Nothing about this in the index of "Programming in Scala" under `=` (nor, for that matter, "assignment" nor "reassignment").  Thank you!

Comment: But say if I make my own class with `+` method and try the above. It works. But instead of `+` if I try say other name of method say `add`, then it doesnt work. `class A(val n:Int){
 def add(o:A) = new A(n+o.n)
 }` and try doing `var i = new A(1); i add= new A(2)`. This doesnt work. Replacing `add` with `+` works as expected. Interesting, is there any thing specified in documentation

Comment: @AdamMackler PiS index under `+=` reassignment with immutable sets and vars. Points to http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/next-steps-in-scala.html#step10 where you not only learn what += means, but that in Scala you "mix in" traits. So much to absorb!

Comment: @Jatin see the SLS quote by @gourlaysama, then see `op` in 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Is this value assigned to a variable? If it's the case I think this syntax sugar:

```
scala> var x = IndexedSeq(1,2,3)
x: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> x :+= 10

scala> x
res59: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 10)

scala> val y = IndexedSeq(1,2,3)
y: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> y :+= 10
<console>:16: error: value :+= is not a member of IndexedSeq[Int]
          y :+= 10
            ^
```

It is syntax sugar for "operation and assignment", like `+=`:

```
scala> var x = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> x += 1

scala> x
res63: Int = 11
```

Which de-sugars to `x = x + 1`.